# Can a bucket name be available after deleting AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

You have an account in AWS. Let's call it Account1.

You create a S3 bucket with the name of 'myBestBucket'. Now the bucket name is not available for any other user in any other account.

Let's say that you now delete your Account1. The account is closed and I guess AWS will delete all resources linked to it.

Would the bucket name ('myBestBucket') be available from another account after sometime?

Answer (score 2):

After deleting a bucket. You have to wait some time to create the bucket with the same name. It is not instantly available after deleting it. It happened to me before. Just wait for some time and try creating it.

Comment: Would it be the same if you don't delete the bucket directly but you delete the AWS account directly?

Comment: As per my knowledge, the bucket still exists if you just delete your account. Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/close-account.html#before-closing

Comment: It _might_ take a considerable time for resources in a 'closed' account to be permanently removed. Therefore, it could be quite some time until a bucket name becomes available again. In theory, an actual bucket name is not important unless it maps to a specific domain (eg a bucket name of `www.example.com`).

Answer (score 2):

It will be available eventually, not really sure of the timing, but when I have had to delete a bucket so that it could be created under another account it only took a matter of minutes (about 3 minutes if I remember correctly); so if the goal is to allow another account to take over a bucket name, I would recommend deleting the bucket, and waiting for it to be available before deleting the account that originally owned the bucket name.

Comment: It looks like this could take up to 90 days.  [*"...90 days after your account is closed (the "Post-Closure Period")... During the Post-Closure Period, AWS may retain any content that you didn't delete and any AWS services that you didn't terminate before you closed your AWS account."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/close-account.html)